# How do you create a function so that it returns a char from an if statement?

Tags: sql-server, function, user-defined-functions

I have a table called EmployeeTransfers with the columns EmpIdSSN, EmpBasePay, EmpTransferState, and EmpFederalFilingStatus. The function I created is taking two parameters which are the state and the filing status, from this it's supposed to determine what the code is by going through the if statements and returning that code. The error I have at the moment is as follows:

> Msg 444, Level 16, State 2, Procedure GetStateFilingStatus, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 62] Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.

My other issue I'm having as well is I want to capture all the other states that are not included in the if statements to send out a generic code 'S' for single and 'M' for married. I attempted to do an else statement at the end but kept running into various errors.

```
create table EmployeeTransfers
(
        EmpIdSSN char(9),
        EmpBasePay decimal(16,4),
        EmpTransferState char(2),
        EmpFederalFilingStatus char(1)
)
GO

--Input data
insert into EmployeeTransfers
values
('555342121',60000.00, 'CA', 'S'),
('552342120',70000.00, 'NY', 'M'),
('552342120',87000.00, 'AZ', 'M'),
('456772332',55000.00, 'CT', 'S'),
('332223445',33000.00, 'NJ', 'M'),
('550667788',54000.00, 'DC', 'M')
GO

create function dbo.GetStateFilingStatus(@EmpFederalFilingStatus char(1), @EmpTransferState char(2))
returns char(1)
as
begin
    declare @StateFilingStatus char;
    select @StateFilingStatus
    from EmployeeTransfers
    where EmpFederalFilingStatus = @EmpFederalFilingStatus
        and EmpTransferState = @EmpTransferState;
    if (@EmpTransferState = 'MS') and (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
        set @StateFilingStatus = 'A';
        else
        set @StateFilingStatus = 'M';
    return @StateFilingStatus;
    if (@EmpTransferState = 'NJ') and (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
        set @StateFilingStatus = 'B';
        else
        set @StateFilingStatus = 'A';
    return @StateFilingStatus;
    if (@EmpTransferState = 'AZ') and (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
        set @StateFilingStatus = 'A';
        else
        set @StateFilingStatus = 'B';
    return @StateFilingStatus;
    if (@EmpTransferState = 'CT') and (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
        set @StateFilingStatus = 'F';
        else
        set @StateFilingStatus = 'M';
    return @StateFilingStatus;
    if (@EmpTransferState = 'DC') and (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
        set @StateFilingStatus = 'S';
        else
        set @StateFilingStatus = 'Y';
    return @StateFilingStatus;
end;
go
```

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: @McNets for the function to output "StateFilingStatus = codeReturned". For example, if you input into the function 'NJ' and 'S' it would return 'B' which is the code.

Comment: as the error says, you are doing this select @StateFilingStatus but functions are designed to return one value, no to execute select statements to be returned. remove that select

Comment: Thare are more errors.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, if your state is 'TX', then your first `if` block is going to go to the `else`, set the `@StateFilingStatus` to `M` and then return that. I think you need to add some nesting.

Comment: @Gonzalo.- I actually used the format for the scalar function from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx which is why I included the select statement.

Comment: @AdamV I had mentioned I had that issue as well where if it's none of the following states I wanted the code to be S for single and M for married. Is it possible to use else if inside a function?

Comment: but scalar format does this SELECT @ret = SUM(p.Quantity)  which is assigning the result from select (a scalar) to a variable. You're not doing dat, you are doing `select @StateFilingStatus from EmployeeTransfers    where EmpFederalFilingStatus = @EmpFederalFilingStatus and EmpTransferState = @EmpTransferState;` and that will try to return a table result from select

Comment: @Gonzalo.- My mistake, thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that what you're trying for is:

```
create function dbo.GetStateFilingStatus(@EmpFederalFilingStatus char(1), @EmpTransferState char(2))
returns char(1)
as
begin
    declare @StateFilingStatus char;
    if (@EmpTransferState = 'MS') 
    begin
        if (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'A';
        else
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'M';
    end
    else
    if (@EmpTransferState = 'NJ') 
    begin
        if (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'B';
        else
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'A';
    end
    else
    if (@EmpTransferState = 'AZ') 
    begin
        if (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'A';
        else
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'B';
    end
    else
    if (@EmpTransferState = 'CT') 
    begin
        if (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'F';
        else
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'M';
    end
    else
    if (@EmpTransferState = 'DC') 
    begin
        if (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'S';
        else
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'Y';
    end
    else
    begin   -- this is your catch-all condition for all other States
        -- you will probably need to modify this because I don't know 
        -- what your criteria are for returning 'S' or 'M'
        if (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'S';
        else
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'M';
    end
    return @StateFilingStatus
end;
go
```

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to achieve, using a begin and end for each if statement allows for it to be skipped over if the argument isn't met then?

Comment: The `begin...end` blocks achieve the nesting suggested by Adam V. The `if` statements outside of the `begin...end` blocks get you into a particular State, then inside the block tells you what to do for each Filing Status once you've decided what the State is.